# Transactions disappearing from local validator rpc

Tags: anchor, rpc, solana-test-validator

I have an issue where after I run `anchor test --detach` (which starts a local validator) the transactions are only available for a short time (a few minutes) via rpc. Possibly a local validator setting concerning making only recent blocks available over rpc?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure about `anchor test` specfically, but `solana-test-validator` (which it probably wraps?) has a very low default `--limit-ledger-size` value to prevent consuming excess disk space.  Assuming `anchor test` can pass this argument through or supports an analog, increasing the value will keep a deeper ledger history around

Comment: Thanks - this was it!
For future reference - the anchor specific fix was to add 
`[test.validator]
limit_ledger_size = "10000000"` (new line after `[test.validator]`) to `Anchor.toml`.